# Python27 zipimport does not recognize .zip file

Tags: python-2.7

I need to import modules such as numpy as zip files from non-standard directories.
I try to import numpy from the full path C:\Users\Anders\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1.zip\ which is downloaded from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.1/numpy-1.8.1.zip/download

Script:

```
import zipimport

zipimport.zipimporter("C:\Users\Anders\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1.zip")
import numpy
```

Output:

```
zipimport.zipimporter("C:\Users\Anders\Downloads\numpy-1.8.1.zip")
ZipImportError: not a Zip file
```

What the heck is that about?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems with `zipimport` unable to parse the full path in Window environments.

The fix I follow is to change directories into the folder containing the zip file.

```
import zipimport
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Anders\Downloads")
zipimport.zipimporter("numpy-1.8.1.zip")
```

Then, I specify a relative path to the zip file. I tested this locally for the case you mentioned without any complications.

Comment: Ah, that fixed the problem of "not a Zip file". But it leaves me with the problem that Numpy is not recognized, "ImportError: No module named numpy".